# Hibernate: saving parent alone when child is empty

Tags: hibernate

I have parent and child tables. parent has set of children. these two tables have one to many relationship. in hbm i mapped one-to-many. my requirement is when children size is empty I should not save the child only parent should be saved. if children size is not empty then both parent and children should be saved. in child table i have 3 columns all are not null columns. i cannot save null values. is it possible in hibernate? if so, please help me in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as long as you `persist` your entity objects, hibernate will do what you want.

If you have not null columns, you must provide values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...is it possible to persist only parent without child when chidl is null?

Comment: Yes. You can have no children by either having a null set or empty set. Don't however put a null into the set.

Answer (score 0):

in hibernate mapping don't `add not-null='true'`

parent.hbm.xml

```
<set cascade="all, delete-orphan" name="child" order-by="param">
      <key>
        <column name="child_parent_id"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="com.Child"/>
</set>
```

child.hbm.xml

```
<many-to-one class="com.Parent" insert="false" name="rateCode" update="false">
      <!-- cascade="all" -->
      <column name="child_parent_id"/>
</many-to-one>
```

java

while `save|saveUpdate`

`parent.addChild = null;`

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks much for your reply. if we use above code, because we are using cascade = all, does hibernate inserts foreign key in child table? if it is inserted then i will have problem because in child table all columns are not null columns.

Comment: as i said while saving parent use child set|list|bag to `NULL` so child id will also be null